# Target of \label placed inaccurately by hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, labels, newtheorem

I have a line like '`\begin{thm}\label{tPrimes}`', where `thm` is defined using `\newtheorem`.

It generates a line starting with 'Theorem 1.2' in bold. It seems that the target defined by `\label` is always one line above the word 'Theorem'. Which is not what I expect but could be acceptable in many cases.

However, if LaTeX places 'Theorem 1.2' on the top of page N, then a click on the text generated by `\ref{tPrimes}`, placed on page N+1, goes to the bottom of page N-1, which is a problem: the reader sees something else than the theorem. I tried to combine `\label` with `\phantomsection`. Then the target is in the right line, but somewhere inside it, exactly where `\label was used`.

Is there a way that would place the target right to the left of the word 'Theorem', no matter whether it opens a page or not?

I am using MikTeX 2.9, LaTeX2e <2015/10/01>, `hyperref[dvipdfm]`.
Thank you, Vitek Svejdar

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{article}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\title{Experiments with labels and hyperref}\author{V.\v S.}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage[dvipdfm,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
%hypertexnames=false,
pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight,%
pdfpagemode=UseNone,%
pdftoolbar=false,%
pdfmenubar=false}%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{First section}
\blindtext
% Theorem 1.1 in the very bottom of page 1:
\begin{thm}\label{tPrimes}
If a prime\/ $p$ is a divisor of a product\/ $a\cdot b$, then it is
a divisor of one of the numbers\/ $a$~and\/~$b$.
\end{thm}
% Theorem 1.2 opens page 2. However, \label places its anchor on page 1:
\begin{thm}\label{tEuclid}
Euclid's group\/ $\Phi(p)$ of every prime\/~$p$ is cyclic.
\end{thm}
% Blind text whose purpose is to get to page 3
\par\blindtext\par\blindtext\par\blindtext
\par
See Theorem \ref{tPrimes} on page~\pageref{tPrimes}.
% \ref correctly generates '1.2', \pageref correctly generates '2',
% but a click on '1.2' takes me to the bottom of page 1:
Theorem~\ref{tEuclid} on page~\pageref{tEuclid} plays a role in the following proof.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Are you using any package to set up your theorems?

Comment: I think not. The two lines \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage[dvipdfm,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}, plus some \hypersetup, is almost everything that I have before \begin{document}. I have a MWE, 32 lines, but I must admit that I do not know how to make it public.

Comment: The instruction `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]` very strongly suggests that you're loading either `amsthm` or `ntheorem`. Which one is it?

Comment: No I am not loading these. Actually, I have nothing in my MWE except hyperref and blindtext.

Comment: @Vitek: Adding a MWE is always a good idea and will definitely be helpful here. Just edit your answer and copy-paste your TeX code into it. Ideally as a [code block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) (for instance: "create code blocks by using “code fences”, consisting of three or more backticks or tildes").

Comment: Thank you, that is a useful tip. I am happy to know what code fences is.

Comment: Loading the `amsthm` package -- *before* issuing the `\newtheorem` directive and loading `hyperref` -- lets you achieve your formatting objective.

Comment: why are you using such an old latex with miktex?

Comment: @Mico -- Yes, I just tested that too.  This means that the "basic" definitions for theorems, in the LaTeX core, are insufficient, and should be reported.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Probably it is not a LaTeX-core-issue but a hyperref-issue related to the "basic definitions" for theorems.

Comment: Thank you all, and especially to Mico, for your comments and explanations. Loading `amsthm` and doing nothing else helped! It only added a period after the number, but I suppose that I will be able to customize it. I just want to explain to David Carlisle that I work on a huge textbook and I hoped that I would be able to finish it before upgrading LaTeX. Other comments suggest that it probably would not help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen as the original design of `\label` predates the internet and was not designed to provide a location for a link anchor. `hyperref` patches things as much as it can so it usually works out alright but theorem layouts are tricky and have many variant definition forms in packages, so catching them all is hard.

If it happens you can always force a better outcome by putting `\clearpage` before the theorem (at the same place that the automatic page break happened) this will ensure that the break happens before the link anchor is generated so the anchor will end up at the top of the next page.

Comment: you could also use `\begin{thm}\leavevmode\phantomsection\label{tEuclid}Euclid ...`. The destination will be a bit displaced to the right (which one could amend) but it will be on the right page.

Comment: Thank you. Actually this is the reason why I started to work on it. I had \phantomsection in my definitions for a long time, but I saw putting the target to the right as a problem. Under some view mode of Reader, jumping to say one inch to the right from the left margin leaves some text out of the screen, which is inconvenient for the user.

Comment: @Vitek you can do something like \hspace*{-1in}\phantomsection\hspace{1in}.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I probably will do if the experiments with `amsthm` fail. In this moment I still hope that I will be able to place the anchor exactly (!) to the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

So it became clear that, unlike the original LaTeX's `\newtheorem`, `amsthm` defines environments with correctly placed anchors. If the visual form of the original `\newtheorem` (no period after the theorem number and the optional argument in boldface) is preferable, then the following setting of `amsthm` can be used:

```
\newtheoremstyle{ltxtheorem}{9.5pt plus 3pt minus 4pt}{9.5pt plus 3pt minus 4pt}%
  {\itshape}{}% Body font, no indentation
  {\bfseries}{}% Head font, no punctuation. Space after the head and the head shape:
  {.5em}{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\hspace{.33333em}#2}\thmnote{\hspace{.33333em}(#3)}}%
```

The lengths are found experimentally, but it more or less works.